# Vectorize hellinger for sparse matrix - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, sparse-matrix

I am trying to find the [Hellinger distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance) between a single distribution `p` and every row of a sparse matrix `dist_mat`. I want to return a vector of dimension 1*N where N is the number of rows in `dist_mat`.

```
def hellinger(p, dist_mat):
    return np.sqrt(1/2) * np.sqrt(  np.sum((np.sqrt(p) - np.sqrt(dist_mat))**2)  )
```

Using the function above, if we try out a test case:

```
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3)).toarray()
test = np.array([0,21,0])
hellinger(test,csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3)))
>>> 4.3633103660024926
```

which returns a scalar, not a vector. So for the example above I want a list of results containing the hellinger distances. Something like:

```
hellinger(test,csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3)))
>>> [3.46,3.46,2.78] # hellinger distance between test and each row of the csr sparse matrix
```

Is there some way I can return the desired vector of distances using numpy notation, perhaps using the [np.apply_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) method? I have seen this done before, but can't seem to get it here. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I want to avoid explicit for loops as these would be inefficient. I am looking for the most optimized / fastest way to do this.

Comment: What's the shape of the sparse matrix for your actual case?

Comment: @Divakar  - it is about 280,000 rows by 6000 columns. The number of rows changes depending on some upstream model output, but the number of columns is always the same. It is extremely sparse, less than 1% of the entries are non zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Vectorized solution

Here's the final vectorized solution that I arrived at through few optimizations and one crucial trick, assuming `s` as the input sparse matrix of type `csr_matrix`.

```
k1 = np.sqrt(1/2)
k2s = np.sqrt(test.dot(test))
out = k1*np.sqrt(k2s + s.sum(1).A1 -2*np.sqrt(s*test))
```

---

#### Playing back the history

The final vectorized solution was reached after a series of optimizations that I would try to playback for my and others reference and I apologize for being verbose here, but I feel that's needed.

**Stage #1**

Starting off with in-ling the func defintiion in a loop :

```
N = s.shape[0]
out = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(s.shape[0]):
    ai = s[i].toarray()
    out[i] = np.sqrt(1/2) * np.sqrt(  np.sum((np.sqrt(test) - np.sqrt(ai))**2)  )
```

**Stage #2**

Get the constants out and perform squared root outside :

```
k1 = np.sqrt(1/2)
k2 - np.sqrt(test)

N = s.shape[0]
out = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(s.shape[0]):
    ai = s[i].toarray()
    out[i] = np.sum((k2 - np.sqrt(ai))**2)

out = np.sqrt(out)
out *= k1
```

**Stage #3 (Crucial trick)**

Crucial trick here as we would use the math formula :

```
(A-B)**2 = A**2) + B**2 - 2*A*B
```

Thus,

```
sum((A-B)**2) = sum(A**2) + sum(B**2) - 2*sum(A*B)
```

The last part `sum(A*B)` is simply matrix multiplication and that's major performance booster here.

Simplifies to :

```
k1 = np.sqrt(1/2)
k2 - np.sqrt(test)

N = s.shape[0]
out = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(s.shape[0]):
    ai = s[i].toarray()
    out[i] = (k2**2).sum() + (np.sqrt(ai))**2).sum() -2*np.sqrt(ai).dot(k2)

out = np.sqrt(out)
out *= k1
```

Further simplifies to :

```
k1 = np.sqrt(1/2)
k2 - np.sqrt(test)

N = s.shape[0]
out = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(s.shape[0]):
    ai = s[i].toarray()
    out[i] = (k2**2).sum() + ai.sum() -2*np.sqrt(ai).dot(k2)

out = np.sqrt(out)
out *= k1
```

**Stage #4**

Get the constant `(k2**2).sum()` out and get the row-wise summation of sparse matrix out too :

```
k1 = np.sqrt(1/2)
k2 - np.sqrt(test)
k2s = (k2**2).sum()

N = s.shape[0]
out = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(s.shape[0]):
    ai = s[i].toarray()
    out[i] =  -2*np.sqrt(ai).dot(k2)

out += k2s + s.sum(1).A1 # row-wise summation of sparse matrix added here
out = np.sqrt(out)
out *= k1
```

**Stage #5**

The final trick is to remove the loop altogether. So, in the loop we have each output element being computed with `np.sqrt(s[i]).dot(k2)`. That matrix-multiplcation could be done across all rows with simply : `np.sqrt(s)*k2`. That's all!

The remains would be :

```
k1 = np.sqrt(1/2)
k2 - np.sqrt(test)
k2s = (k2**2).sum()

out = -2*np.sqrt(s)*k2 # Loop gone here
out += k2s + s.sum(1).A1
out = np.sqrt(out)
out *= k1
```

That simplifies to after using `inner` dot product to get `k2s` -

```
k1 = np.sqrt(1/2)
k2 = np.sqrt(test)
k2s = k2.dot(k2)
out = k1*np.sqrt(k2s + s.sum(1).A1 -2*np.sqrt(s)*k2)
```

We could avoid the square-root computation for `test` to get `k2` and thus further simplify things like so -

```
k1 = np.sqrt(1/2)
k2s = np.sqrt(test.dot(test))
out = k1*np.sqrt(k2s + s.sum(1).A1 -2*np.sqrt(s*test))
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Could you please elaborate on what you did and what the crucial trick is?

Comment: @killerT2333 Added.

Comment: How would we extend this if the 1 dimensional vector `p` was also a sparse csr array? So in other words, both inputs into the hellinger function would be sparse? If we use the current method we get `dimension mismatch`

Answer (score 0):

Basing my answer on @Divakar's...

If the distributions $P$ and $Q$ that we are inputting into the Hellinger function are normalized (so $\sum_i P_i = 1$) (which they are in my case), then the function simplifies to

$\sqrt{1 - \sum_i^k \sqrt{P_iQ_i}}$

This works even if $Q$ is a matrix of row wise distribution vectors.

So we can write

```
def hellinger(p,dist_mat): 
    out = np.sqrt(1 - np.sqrt(dist_mat*p.T).toarray())
    return out.T[0]
```

Some points

- I use `.toarray()` because I cannot subtract a scalar from a sparse vector - we would get the error `NotImplementedError: adding a nonzero scalar to a sparse matrix is not supported`
- I need to take the dot product between `dist_mat` and `p.T`, the transpose of `p`, so dimensions match
- I return `out` transposed and it's first element, to output the desired vector
- This works for **sparse** inputs `p` and `dist_mat`